# Switch gst video to some point in another video on pygtk Button press

Tags: python, video, pygtk, gstreamer

I'm trying to play a video and have a button that switches the video to a new one, *starting the new one at some point other than the beginning*. I haven't written much UI or video-related code.

I have the following that kind of works (very trimmed):

```
class Main(gobject.GObject):
  def __init__(self):
    self.player = gst.element_factory_make('playbin', 'VideoPlayer')
    #.. pygtk UI/Button code

  def next_video(self):
    self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
    self.player.set_property('uri', 'next_video_path')
    self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PAUSED)
    end = time.time() + 1
    while time.time() < end:
      pass
    self.player.seek_simple(gst.FORMAT_TIME, gst.SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, 100000000000)
    self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Main(sys.argv)
  gtk.main()
```

A couple points:

- I'm using GObject because I wanted to be able to use gobject.timeout_add, since I need something to happen periodically. I'm not married to it if there's another way.
- Without that 1 second wait, it doesn't work. Using time.sleep() causes a seg fault.
- I do sometimes see a blip of the beginning of the video, and sometimes it just starts from the beginning.
- It has been suggested I have a background playbin and 'hot swap' them. This would be fine - I'm just not sure how to do it.

Obviously, I'd like a cleaner, more reliable way to do this.

**TL;DR: How can I switch from video to video in a pygtk window, starting at an arbitrary point in the video?**

Comment: First of all, don't trim your code.  Show the complete code or link to it.  For example, you probably need to do gobject.threads_init() and your code doesn't show you doing that.  Next, going to PAUSED can take time.  You can either wait for it (with wait_state I believe) in a blocking way, or attach a bus handler for state change messages.  You should not perform the seek until the pipeline actually changed to PAUSED.  The time hack should not be needed if you do this and is not correct anyway.  I don't see you using gobject_timeout_add in your code, so not sure why you mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting one second, use something like `self.player.get_state(timeout=3*gst.SECOND)` to wait for the switch to `gst.STATE_PAUSED` to complete.

The timeout is used because if an error occurs and GStreamer doesn't succeed at changing the pipeline state, a `get_state` without a timeout will just get stuck waiting forever.

Comment: Thanks. This gets rid of the jitter.